# Increase File Upload Size Wordpress / IIS 7

Tags: php, wordpress, iis-7, web-config

I'm trying to increase the file upload size in a Wordpress blog to allow an admin to post his e-books and large PDF files.  The site is hosted on GoDaddy / IIS 7.  I have tried the following with no luck:
web.config:
`<configuration><system.webServer><security><requestFiltering><requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="10000000"/></requestFiltering></security></system.webServer></configuration>`

php.ini in root of site:
`upload_max_filesize = 64M`

Any advice is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Shawn

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solution found here:

Step 1:

> First, you need to edit your server’s PHP.ini file. This is found in
> your PHP installation directory, e.g. c:\program files\php\php.ini and
> set the following values:
>
> upload_max_filesize = 64M
> post_max_size = 64M
> max_execution_time = 300
> max_input_time = 300
>
> This allows PHP to handle files up to 64MB and allows PHP scripts to
> run up to 5 minutes before timing out.

Step 2:

> Lastly, IIS 7 has a default file upload limit of 30MB. Anything larger
> than that will cause IIS to return a very unhelpful 404 status. You
> can read more about it at
> http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits
>
> To override this, you need to change the web.config settings for
> (each) site. (The only catch here is that the limits are expected to
> be in bytes instead of kilobytes.) The following is some copypasta
> from the MSDN docs:

Don’t forget to recycle your application pool so IIS picks up your
PHP.ini changes.

And that’s it!

http://refactored.tumblr.com/post/4609761388/wordpress-iis7-uploads

Answer (score 2):

you will have to modify the active php.ini which you can get get from a phpinfo() and change both post_max_size and upload_max_filesize  accordingly.  Once done, restart iis

Comment: Okay, so I've done this and re-tried uploading a large file (~36MB) with the flash uploader & the browser uploader.  The browser uploader times out and shows "Cannot display page", and the flash one says "HTTP Error".  Is there a timeout I need to revise in the php.ini file? Is it default_socket_timeout?

Comment: I've also updated the following in php.ini with no success:
1. max_input_time: 300
2. max_execution_time: 300
3. memory_limit: 128M

Comment: @pharophy can you figure out how to make it at last? I wanna make it but failed too, please help!

Comment: i figured it out, please refer to my answer

Answer (score 2):

I had to adapt the first solution above, because I am using Windows Share HostGator site. I had a file in httpdocs called: .user.ini, which I added:

```
upload_max_filesize = 256M
post_max_size = 256M
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
```

Because I needed it bigger. I also added:

```
<security><requestFiltering><requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="268435456"/> 
</requestFiltering></security>
```

So this allowed me upload larger files. I wanted to be able to upload large videos or mp3 files.

Comment: Hi @JohnFoll , I also have a windows Share Hostgator site, but this solution is not working for me, is there any new change that needs to added by any chance?

I can provide my .user.ini file for reference if required.