# $_FILES is empty for large file upload

Tags: php, iis

I'm trying to upload the big file in PHP on IIS server. I'm using **PHP 7.1** and **IIS 8.5**. The file upload works for files smaller than 1 GB. But if I try to upload file bigger than 1 GB, the $_FILES variable is empty array.

The error_get_last() gives the error

> POST Content-Length of 1388289413 bytes exceeds the limit of
>   1073741824 bytes

*. I've checked all the configurations and they all are in order.

I have following configuration in web.config file

```
<security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
        </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Also settings in php.ini are as

```
memory_limit = 3G
post_max_size = 3G
upload_max_filesize = 3G
```

What am I still missing?
Can you guys help me out with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you restart apache server after updating php.ini file?

Comment: Its an IIS server, and yes it was restarted.

Comment: Please go this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103717/increase-file-upload-size-wordpress-iis-7). This is same problem as yours.

Comment: I tried those things, but it is still not working

Comment: try to edit applicationhost.config file which is located at "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config" modify this <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength ="<length>" /> configuration data inside the <requestFiltering> section. after doing this restart the iis server.

Comment: Always verify that the settings are actually active by checking `phpinfo()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the value in `MB`. Convert the GB into necessary MB.

Suppose for 2GB,

**php_value memory_limit 2048M**

Also, please edit the file called php.ini not the Apache file

Answer (score 0):

Upload the data in chunks:

https://www.plupload.com/

plupload is a javascript/php library, and it's quite easy to use and allows chunking.

Tomorrow maybe you'll need to upload a 5 or 10GB file, it's better to use chunking.